# CASE statement: Inconsistent conversion fail error - varchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```sql
    SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN Employees.first_name IS NULL
      OR Employees.first_name = 'x' THEN Employees.last_name
      WHEN Employees.credentials IS NULL THEN Employees.last_name + ', ' + Employees.first_name
      ELSE Employees.last_name + ', ' + Employees.first_name + ' - ' + Employees.credentials
   END,
   Employees.num3,
   Employees.address1 + '  ' + Employees.city + ', ' + Employees.state + '  ' + Employees.zip,
   Employees.work_phone,
   CASE
      WHEN Clients.age <= 18 THEN 'Youth'
      ELSE 'Adult'
   END,
   Clients.client_id,
   Clients.last_name + ', ' + Clients.first_name,
   ClientVisit.cptcode,
   ClientVisit.visittype,
   ClientVisit.rev_timeout,
   ClientVisit.timein,
   ClientVisit.duration,
   SUM(CASE
      WHEN ClientVisit.cptcode = 90791 THEN 200
      WHEN ClientVisit.comb_units = 1 THEN 85.67
      ELSE ClientVisit.comb_units * 21.4175
   END),
   DATEDIFF(d, ClientVisit.rev_timeout, ClientVisit.signature_datetime)
FROM dbo.ClientVisit
INNER JOIN dbo.Employees
ON (
   ClientVisit.by_emp_id = Employees.emp_id
)
INNER JOIN dbo.Programs
ON (
   ClientVisit.program_id = Programs.program_id
)
INNER JOIN dbo.Clients
ON (
   Clients.client_id = ClientVisit.client_id
)
WHERE (
   ClientVisit.rev_timeout BETWEEN '20160401 11:40:00.000' AND '20160415 11:40:16.000'
   AND Programs.program_desc IN ('Off Panel')
   AND ClientVisit.non_billable = 0
   AND ClientVisit.cptcode NOT IN ('00000', '0124', '100', '1001', '101', '102', '103', '80100', '9079', '99999')
   AND Employees.num3 IS NOT NULL
)
GROUP BY 
   CASE
      WHEN Clients.age <= 18 THEN 'Youth'
      ELSE 'Adult'
   END,
   CASE
      WHEN Employees.first_name IS NULL
      OR Employees.first_name = 'x' THEN Employees.last_name
      WHEN Employees.credentials IS NULL THEN Employees.last_name + ', ' + Employees.first_name
      ELSE Employees.last_name + ', ' + Employees.first_name + ' - ' + Employees.credentials
   END,
   DATEDIFF(d, ClientVisit.rev_timeout, ClientVisit.signature_datetime),
   ClientVisit.cptcode,
   Clients.last_name + ', ' + Clients.first_name,
   Clients.client_id,
   Employees.address1 + '  ' + Employees.city + ', ' + Employees.state + '  ' + Employees.zip,
   Employees.work_phone,
   ClientVisit.duration,
   ClientVisit.visittype,
   ClientVisit.rev_timeout,
   ClientVisit.timein,
   Employees.num3
```

Gives me the Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'H2019' to data
>   type int.

I'm unable to locate specifically where this conversion is taking place and what could be a possible fix.

EDIT: Located problem in cptcode column which has alphanumeric entries. However, changing date ranges in WHERE clause gives results for some dates and not for others.

Comment: Well, they're unnecessary, they don't add any value at all, and just make reading your query that much harder....

Comment: Never use `select distinct` and `group by`  in a single select, remove distinct as it achieves nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use

```
"ClientVisit"."cptcode" = 90791
```

the data type of 90791 will be integer. If you replace it with

```
"ClientVisit"."cptcode" = '90791'
```

both sides of the equation will be characters. You can also do something like:

```
 "ClientVisit"."cptcode" = CAST(90791 AS VARCHAR(20))
```

The reasons for your problem is that SQL Server will do an [implicit conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx). In this case to integer as Integer has a higher [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) than (n)(var)char data types.

Of course I do not know your data but I guess there are data ranges where there is only numeric values for cptcode. So your code will work for them but not if you hit something like e.g. H006

Hope that helps ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does! :)

Answer (score 2):

Comment out all the colums in the select segment and start ucommenting them one by one while executing the select each time. When you uncomment the problematic line, you'll find the source of the error.

BTW: I'm guessing the problem is in `"ClientVisit"."cptcode" = 90791`.

Comment: Turns out to that is the problem. I have some cptcodes as one alphabet followed by 4 numbers. Eg: H006, G0409 etc. How do I make this case statement work with such data in my field?

Comment: What is strange is that when I change rev_timeout ranges in the `WHERE` clause to any date range except at a date later than 4th April, 2016, the query executes.
Even though cptcode still has alphanumeric codes inside. It was my understanding that all result expressions in CASE statement must have same data type. Which could be the reason for the conversion error. But the error is not consistent as the date range changes make it work. What could be the reason?

Comment: Different date ranges result in a differet sets of values in the `cptcode` column. Sometimes the column values dont have alpha values, sometimes they do.

Comment: So the CASE statement won't compare each value in cptcode with `90791`. And give results for only those date ranges where cptcode is not alphanumeric?